# merging a sequence of maps

Tags: clojure, hashmap

I have two maps, of the form:

```
(def h1 {:p1 {:x {:port :p1 :instr :x :qty 10}}})
(def h2 {:p1 {:y {:port :p1 :instr :y :qty 11}}})
```

When I merge them using

```
(apply (partial merge-with merge) [h1 h2])
```

I get the correct result:

```
-> {:p1 {:y {:port :p1, :qty 11, :instr :y}, :x {:port :p1, :qty 10, :instr :x}}
```

However, If I try reducing over a sequence of maps:

```
(reduce (fn [r m] apply (partial merge-with merge) r m) {} [h1 h2])
```

I get only the first map as a result:

```
-> {:p1 {:y {:port :p1, :qty 11, :instr :y}}}
```

I would expect the same result. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to apply the `apply`. In

```
(fn [r m] apply (partial merge-with merge) r m)
```

... the implicit `do` in the `fn` form performs a series of evaluations, returning the result of the last one. Ignoring side-effects (and there are none), the function is equivalent to

```
(fn [r m] m)
```

as you observed.

The `reduce` takes the sequence of maps apart, so you don't need the `apply`:

```
(reduce (fn [r m] (merge-with merge r m)) {} [h1 h2])
; {:p1
;  {:y {:qty 11, :instr :y, :port :p1},
;   :x {:qty 10, :instr :x, :port :p1}}}
```

If you are determined to use the same structure for the function, you have to do it this way:

```
(reduce (fn [r m] (apply (partial merge-with merge) [r m])) {} [h1 h2])
; {:p1
;  {:y {:qty 11, :instr :y, :port :p1},
;   :x {:qty 10, :instr :x, :port :p1}}}
```

`apply` expects a sequence as its last argument, which it flattens into the trailing arguments to its first (function) argument.

Comment: Thanks. that suddenly makes a whole lot of sense.